# compare a python panda frame in if logic

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe return from a SQL

assuming

````
df="the data frame value of the sql result" . # the sql is ```select 2```

print(df) #return 0    2

print(type(df))  #return <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
````

then i want to make an if logic to see if the this data frame value equals to 2 or not. I have tried many ways but nothing works

```
if df.astype(str) == str(2):

  do something

else:

  do others
```

errors

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any good way to do so? Thank you!

Comment: follow this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem based on the information above!